# Counting all $n$ with $p\mid n^n -1$ for given $p$ prime

Tags: number-theory, divisibility, natural-numbers

Say I have a prime $p$. I choose a number $n$ in the interval $[1, p^{p}]$ so that $p$ divides $n^{n}{-}1$. Now, can we quantify the cardinality of the set containing all possible values of $n$?

Comment: $n$ seems to be rather a positive integer than a set. Please formulate your question clearer.

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format math on this site.  To begin with, enclose all math expressions (including numbers) in `$` signs.  For example, `$x_1^2$` will give you $x_1^2$.  You'll get a much better response if your posts are easy to read.

Comment: Clearly we must have $p\nmid n$, then we can find $n^n=g^{kn}\pmod{p}$ where $g$ is primitive root. Then we can find that $kn\equiv 0\pmod{p}$, so we simply need to find the number of $n$ such that $p\nmid n$ and $kn\equiv 0\pmod{p}$ for some $p\nmid k$.

Comment: @saulspatz This question is well readable , but unfortunately hard to understand. Mathjax is definitely not the problem here.

Comment: @Peter Yes, I just have a standard comment I paste in.  Not exactly applicable here, I grant you.

Comment: @Peter fixed it, I'm apologetic about the ambiguous wording here

Comment: @TheBestMagician could you please elaborate? I'm sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: I updated for clarity as I understand the question - please check that I have correctly captured your intent

Comment: Yes totally @Joffan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expression $n^n\bmod p$ has the base periodic with period $p$ and the exponent periodic with period $p-1$, therefore the expression $n^n\bmod p$ itself has period $p(p-1)$.

The solutions to $n^n\equiv1$ mod $p$ can be constructed from residues $n\equiv k$ mod $p$ by solving

$$ \begin{cases}
n\equiv k \bmod p \\ n\equiv 0 \bmod |k|
 \end{cases} $$

where $|k|$ is the multiplicative order of $k$ mod $p$. These solutions have period $p|k|$, so in the interval $[1,p(p-1)]$ there are $(p-1)/|k|$ such solutions, and the total number is

$$ f=\sum_{k\bmod p} \frac{p-1}{|k|}. $$

Note $k=0$ is excluded. The multiplicative group of integers mod $p$ is cyclic of order $m=p-1$, so there are $\phi(d)$ elements $k$ of order $|k|=d$ for every divisor $d\mid m$. So we may write

$$ f=m\sum_{d\mid m}\frac{\phi(d)}{d}. $$

Since $\phi(d)/d$ is multiplicative, so too is the sum as a function of $m$, so it suffices to evaluate for $m=q^s$ a prime power, which yields $\sum_{t=0}^s \phi(q^t)/q^t=1+s(1-1/q)$, so this expression is

$$ f=m\prod_{q\mid m}\left[1+v_q(m)\left(1-\frac{1}{q}\right)\right], $$

where $q$ runs over prime divisors of $m$.

Since $p^p\equiv p\bmod p(p-1)$, the # of solutions to $n^n\equiv 1$ mod $p$ in the interval $[1,p^p]$ is

$$ N=\frac{p^{p-1}-1}{p-1}f+g $$

where $g$ is the number of solutions in the interval $[1,p]$ (which I expect has no formula).